# C++ Convert Unix time (nanoseconds) to readable datetime in local timezone

Tags: c++, time, c++17, c++20, c++-chrono

I have a Unix time (nanoseconds since epoch) and I would like to go back and forth between this and a readable string in a specifiable timezone (using TZ strings), with nanoseconds preserved. I am using C++17 but willing to migrate to C++20 if it would make things much easier.

Example:

```
uint64_t unix_time = 1669058870115719258;
std::string datetime = convert_unix_to_datetime(unix_time, "America/Detroit");
std::cout << datetime << "\n";
std::cout << convert_datetime_to_unix_time(datetime) << "\n";
```

Desired output:

```
2021-11-21 14:27:50.115719258
1669058870115719258
```

Apologies if this is a basic question--I have searched around the site and tried to implement solutions but keep getting confused by different C++ versions, whether the datetime is in UTC or local timezone, different types like chrono::time_point vs. time_t etc. Hoping to find a simple solution here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using C++20, this is very easy.  Using C++11/14/17 it is harder but doable with a [free, open-source time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Here is what it looks like with C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string
convert_unix_to_datetime(std::uint64_t unix_time, std::string const& tz)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    sys_time<nanoseconds> tp{nanoseconds{unix_time}};
    return format("{:%F %T} ", zoned_time{tz, tp}) + tz;
}
```

The first line converts the `uint64_t`, first into a `nanoseconds` `chrono::duration`, and then into a `nanoseconds`-precision `chrono::time_point` based on `system_clock`.  `chrono::system_clock` uses [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as its measure: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1

The second line creates a `chrono::zoned_time` from the time zone name, and the `sys_time` timepoint.  A `zoned_time` is a simple pairing of these two objects from which you can extract a *local time*.  When formatted, it is the local time that is printed.  Here I've used "%F %T" as the format which will output with the syntax: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff`.  [Many formatting flags are available.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.format#tab:time.format.spec).

Finally I've added the time zone name to the timestamp.  This is done so that the parsing function can recover the time zone name as it is not passed in as one of the parameters to `convert_datetime_to_unix_time`.

```
std::uint64_t
convert_datetime_to_unix_time(std::string s)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    istringstream in{std::move(s)};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    std::string tz_name;
    local_time<nanoseconds> tp;
    in >> parse("%F %T %Z", tp, tz_name);
    zoned_time zt{tz_name, tp};
    return zt.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

The first line moves the string into a `istringstream` as the parsing must use a stream.  I've set the stream to throw an exception if there is a syntax error in the input `s`.  If you would rather check for `failbit` manually, remove the line that sets `failbit` to throw an exception.

Next arguments are default constructed which will be parsed into:

```
std::string tz_name;
local_time<nanoseconds> tp;
```

Here it is important to use the type `local_time` as opposed to `sys_time` because it is the local time that was formatted out.  Use of the `local_time` type informs the library how to apply the UTC offset under the `zoned_time` constructor after `parse`.

The `parse` can pick up the time zone name with the `%Z` flag, and will place it in the last argument to `parse`.

Construct the `zoned_time` with the time zone and time point.

Finally, the `sys_time` (Unix Time) can be extracted from the `zoned_time` with the `.get_sys_time()` member function.  This will have precision `nanoseconds` since the input `local_time` has precision `nanoseconds`.  The underlying integral count of `nanoseconds` is extracted with `.time_since_epoch().count()`.

Using your example driver, this will output:

```
2022-11-21 14:27:50.115719258 America/Detroit
1669058870115719258
```

As I write this, only the latest MSVC tools fully implement this part of C++20.

---

If you need to use the [free, open-source time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), a few minor changes are needed:

- Add `using namespace date;` to each function.
- Change the format string from `"{:%F %T} "` to `"%F %T "`.
- Add `#include "date/tz.h"`.
- Compile and link to tz.cpp using the instructions at https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation

This will by default download a copy of the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), though there are ways to avoid that on non-Windows platforms (described in the installation instructions).

---

### Response to [Tom's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76949858/576911)

Which starts off with:

> Since we're looking at a date and time output that specifies seconds (and nanoseconds) it is worth pointing out that mixing sys_time or zoned_time with civil date and time representations is inherently approximate, the current error being 27 seconds...

And ends with:

> Aside: IMHO, utc_clock should be dropped...

`std::chrono::system_clock` is a simple wrapper around the same clock that the C `time()` function references, which in turn is a simple wrapper around an OS clock.  It turns out in practice that all these clocks measure [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):  A count of time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds.

C++20 introduces `std::chrono::utc_clock` so that if need be, you can subtract two points in time and take into account the leap seconds that (if any) that `system_clock` ignores.

For example, here is a short program that finds the number of elapsed seconds from 2010-01-01 00:00:00 EST to 2020-01-01 00:00:00 EST where EST is the abbreviation for the time zone America/New_York:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace std;
    
    auto tz = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    auto t0 = tz->to_sys(local_days{January/1/2010});
    auto t1 = tz->to_sys(local_days{January/1/2020});
    seconds without_leap_seconds = t1 - t0;
    auto with_leap_seconds = clock_cast<utc_clock>(t1)
                           - clock_cast<utc_clock>(t0);
    cout << "Seconds from the start of 2010 to the start of 2020 in New York:\n";
    cout << "without leap seconds = " << without_leap_seconds << '\n';
    cout << "with    leap seconds = " << with_leap_seconds << '\n';
}
```

The program starts with local times indicating the New Year in New York, and then converts those to `sys_time`, which is the C++20 name for time points associated with `system_clock`, and that [is specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system.overview#1) to model [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

The program computes the difference in `sys_time`, and then also converts both time points to `utc_time` which [is specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc.overview#1) to include leap seconds, and the difference is computed again.

The output of this program is:

```
Seconds from the start of 2010 to the start of 2020 in New York:
without leap seconds = 315532800s
with    leap seconds = 315532803s
```

Note that the value without leap seconds is a multiple of 86400s, and the value with leap seconds is 3s greater.  This is consistent with this [table of leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

[Working demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QBILMn09hHFJZJ1Z)

I write this to demonstrate how C++20 can be used to correctly account for leap seconds, even when the input is civil date and time representations.

Comment: Thanks Howard, this is very helpful. I installed gcc 12.1 (the latest available on RedHat via gcc-toolset), which allows `-std=c++20`, but it looks like `format` and `zoned_time` are not supported. I am now trying to get your library working, but gcc is not liking `-lcurl` for some reason, and still fails even when I point to `libcurl.so`. In the meantime, a couple follow ups: 1. If I wanted to print out UTC datetimes only, is this doable without a library? 2. In your library, it looks like db lookups are fairly involved, with multithreading. Do you know the rough latency of the TZ operations?

Comment: Since `-lcurl` is giving you problems, and you're on Linux (I presume), try compiling both your source and tz.cpp with `-DUSE_OS_TZDB=1` on the command line, and without `-lcurl`.  This instructs the library to use your OS's IANA database that it already has.

Comment: If you don't need time zone support (UTC only), then you can use the header `date.h` at the same location, without tz.cpp.  `date.h` is a header-only library (which tz.h builds upon).  You can use `format` and `parse` with `sys_time`.  `local_time` and `zoned_time` will not be available.

Comment: The timing of operations varies greatly with which operation, and which configuration flags (such as `USE_OS_TZDB`).  So it is difficult for me to give a specific number.  I can say that everything is thread safe.  There are no mutable globals or other data that can be changed by one thread to infect the behavior of other threads.  This is not true of the C timing API where there are infamous thread safety issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're looking at a date and time output that specifies seconds (and nanoseconds) it is worth pointing out that mixing sys_time or zoned_time with civil date and time representations is inherently approximate, the current error being 27 seconds, the number of leap seconds which have been "added to" UTC, on which modern dates and times are based. sys_time and zoned_time are time systems based on an epoch and a steadily increasing duration while UTC tries to reconcile the irregular spin of the Earth with clock time by adding or subtracting leap seconds. Unless these leap seconds are taken into account, sys_time and zoned_time (and Unix time) don't accurately reflect UTC or the calendars that use it.

Of course, there's utc_clock, which may be used to do the leap seconds additions, and accurate results may be obtained using Howard's library or, eventually, perhaps, std::chrono. However, proceed with great care if using utc_clock. utc_clock is a duration-based clock, but UTC is not duration-based and is only a clock in the loose sense that a calendar is a clock. Like a calendar, it is a human convention which gets tampered with from time to time. The result is, converting between utc_time and sys_time **gives time_points with different durations** despite having the same epoch, as if the leap seconds added to UTC were actual real seconds of time, magically created and given to humanity, unbeknownst to the clocks :)

[ Aside: IMHO, utc_clock should be dropped. If accuracy down to seconds is intended, UTC, local times / zoned_times and calendars should be in a category entirely separate from duration-based time systems (sys_clock, steady_clock, tai_clock, gps_clock) and they should only connect to each other via an adapter that handles leap seconds. The standard recognises that calendars are not clocks, and treats them separately, but then interfaces them with the clocks by directly converting to sys_time without doing the necessary and simple arithmetic / lookup needed to account for leap seconds. For a lot of applications, 27 seconds is a significant error.]

So, if accuracy is needed, understand what you are doing and proceed with caution.

Comment: The use case for `std::chrono::utc_clock` is that you can subtract two `time_point`s based on this clock and if those two `time_point`s straddle one or more leap second insertions, those leap seconds are taken into account in the subtraction and you get the correct elapsed duration.  I.e. there is no 27s error.